# Two sorting algorithms give me two different outputs on the same array (quickSort and heapSort)!

Tags: c++, sorting

I don't understand why they give me different output when I compile them. For example ... when I compile only one algorithm the answer is good, the same is for the other one, but when I compile them both at the same time they give me some weird output.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int parent(int i){
    return i/2;
}
int leftChild(int i){
    return 2*i+1;
}
int rightChild(int i){
    return 2*i+2;
}
void maxHeapify(int a[], int i, int n){
    int largest;
    int temp;
    int l = leftChild(i);
    int r = rightChild(i);
    //   p.countOperation("CMPbottomUp",n);
    if (l <= n && (a[l] > a[i]))
        largest = l;
    else
        largest = i;
    //      p.countOperation("CMPbottomUp",n);
    if (r <= n && (a[r] > a[largest]))
        largest = r;
    if (largest != i){
        //    p.countOperation("ATTbottomUp",n);
        temp = a[i];
        //  p.countOperation("ATTbottomUp",n);
        a[i] = a[largest];
        //p.countOperation("ATTbottomUp",n);
        a[largest] = temp;
        maxHeapify(a, largest, n);
    }
}

void buildMaxHeap(int a[], int n){
    for (int i=n/2; i>=0; i--){
        maxHeapify(a, i, n);
    }
}
void heapSort(int a[],int n){
    buildMaxHeap(a,n);
    int n1=n;
    int temp;
    for(int i=n1;i>0;i--){
        temp = a[0];
        a[0] = a[i];
        a[i] = temp;
        n1--;
        maxHeapify(a,0,n1);
    }

}

int partitionArray(int arr[], int left, int right){
    int i = left, j = right;
    int tmp;
    int pivot = arr[(left + right) / 2];
    while (i <= j) {
        while (arr[i] < pivot)
            i++;
        while (arr[j] > pivot)
            j--;
        if (i <= j) {
            tmp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = tmp;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
    return i;
}

void quickSort(int arr[], int left, int right) {
    int index;
    index = partitionArray(arr, left, right);
    if (left < index - 1)
        quickSort(arr, left, index - 1);
    if (index < right)
        quickSort(arr, index, right);
}

int main(){
    int x[8]= {5,87,21,4,12,7,44,3};
    int a[8];
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
        a[i] = x[i];
    }
    heapSort(x,8);
    quickSort(a,0,8);

    for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
        cout<<a[i]<<' ';
    }
    cout<<endl;

    for(int j=0;j<8;j++){
        cout<<x[j]<<' ';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Example output:

1) When I compile only one algorithm the output is : 3,4,5,7,12,21,44,87 (which is good)

2) When I compile both of them in the code the output is: 87,4,5,7,12,21,44,87 (quickSort) and 3,3,4,5,7,12,21,44 (heapSort)

Comment: and turn on compiler warnings...

Comment: Compiling a program ok just lets you know that the code is *syntactically* correct. It doesn't guarantee that your program will run correctly. If the program doesn't work as expected, then you debug the program. Did you expect to write perfect programs all the time and never expect to debug them?

Comment: Hint: people are much more likely to look at your code if you indent it properly. Avoid tab chars and use the `{}` toolbar icon in question editor and look at the preview before posting.

Comment: If I was to guess, in one of your methods, you probably overflow the array. But like others have said, you need to debug it...

Comment: **Most Likely Your Code Invokes Undefined Behaviour!** Check for invalid indices.

Comment: **Alright. I saw your code. Index goes out of the range!**

Comment: What do you mean when you are saying when I compile only one algorithm ??? I tried your code but I do'nt have the same output that you are saying to have. Wether with one or both, the ouputs are wrong

Comment: You should read [this blog post by Eric Lipper](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) which explains how to debug small programs such as yours.

Comment: I'd post the problem in quicksort, but it looks as if @Nawaz is about to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that should work:

```
heapSort(x,7);
quickSort(a,0,7);
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays `a` and `x` are right next to each others in stack. Seeing how you have duplicate value `87` in output, it seems your sort functions access memory outside the array you give to them. This is buffer overrun, a type of Undefined Behaviour. With that, your code could do anything because you have corrupted variable values (or worse, corrupted addresses/pointers).

Double check how you access arrays. Remember that C array indexes for your arrays of length 8 are 0..7!